# Timeout crash on launch (0x8badf00d) due to com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq in iPhone app

Tags: ios, crash, timeout, watchdog

I am getting a weird timeout crash via iTunes during app launch. Here is the stack trace. Seems like something to do with the location service (yes, I do ask for a user's location). Does anyone have any experience with such a crash?

```
Thread 10 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.locationd.registration.xpcq
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x313dd2c8 semaphore_timedwait_trap
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x322db0e6 _dispatch_semaphore_wait_slow
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x322db154 dispatch_semaphore_wait$VARIANT$up
3   CoreLocation                    0x349cd838 CLClientInvokeCallback(__CLClient*, CLClientEvent, __CFDictionary const*)
4   CoreLocation                    0x349cffc0 ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0
5   CoreLocation                    0x34a00c06 CLConnection::handleMessage(CLConnectionMessage*)
6   CoreLocation                    0x34a01a14 __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0
7   libxpc.dylib                    0x349c190a __XPC_CONNECTION_FAULT_BOUNDARY__
8   libxpc.dylib                    0x349badae _xpc_connection_recv_message
9   libxpc.dylib                    0x349bab5e _xpc_connection_wakeup_recv
10  libxpc.dylib                    0x349baa24 _xpc_connection_wakeup2
11  libxpc.dylib                    0x349ba462 _xpc_connection_wakeup
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x322dc21e _dispatch_source_invoke
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x322d9b70 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x322d9caa _dispatch_queue_drain
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x322d9b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x322d9caa _dispatch_queue_drain
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x322d9b66 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$up
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x322da76c _dispatch_worker_thread2
19  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3351d4b0 _pthread_wqthread
20  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3351d384 start_wqthread
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I resolved it by rebooting my iOS device entirely.

I believe the issue is that the remote debug server is in an unexpected state and causing the app to break the running application (libxpc is involved in remote debugging I believe). As a result the best way to clean this up is to simply reboot.

Comment: I encountered the same thing, but I'm not running under the debugger.  This is on the device, untethered.